# 2 разных решения одной задачи через f-строки. Помогите понять разницу

Tags: python-3.6

Задача стояла так:

> Давайте приведём в порядок чек, который печатали ранее. Все строки
> должны быть длиной в 35 символов.

Надо было сделать подобие чека, выровнять строки и при этом они не должны быть длиннее 35 символов.

Мое решение:

```
product_name = input()
product_price = int(input())
product_weight = int(input())
user_money = int(input())

print('================Чек================'[:35])
print(f"Товар: {product_name: >28}"[:35])
print(f"Цена: {product_weight: >15}кг * {product_price}руб/кг"[:35])
print(f"Итого: {product_weight * product_price: >25}руб"[:35])
print(f"Внесено: {user_money: >23}руб"[:35])
print(f"Сдача: {user_money - (product_weight * product_price): >25}руб"[:35])
print('==================================='[:35])
```

И оно было не принято проверяющей системой. Понять за что именно не получилось.

Решение, которое нашлось в интернете и было принято:

```
name = input()
price = int(input())
total = int(input())
money = int(input())
print("================Чек================")
print(f"Товар:{' ' * (29 - len(name))}{name}")
print(f"Цена:{' ' * (19 - len(str(price)) - len(str(total)))}{total}кг * {price}руб/кг")
print(f"Итого:{' ' * (26 - len(str(total * price)))}{total * price}руб")
print(f"Внесено:{' ' * (24 - len(str(money)))}{money}руб")
print(f"Сдача:{' ' * (26 - len(str(money - total * price)))}{money - total * price}руб")
print("===================================")
```

Мне физически больно смотреть на второе решение. Я абсолютно не понимаю, откуда взяты цифры, от которых длина значений отнимается и вообще всё очень страшно выглядит.. чем отличается моё решение от взятого из интернета? Может быть кто-то сможет мне подсказать какие-то краевые кейсы, на которых моё решение может ломаться. ☹️

Comment: Как минимум, первое решение обрезает строки, а второе решение нет (не знаю, учитывает ли это проверяющая система, но всё-таки); ещё в первом решении пробелы после двоеточий есть всегда, а во втором не всегда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если разбирать по каждому print-у, то в правильном решении:

```
   print("================Чек================")
```

Длина строки == 35, здесь ничего не меняем

```
print(f"Товар:{' ' * (29 - len(name))}{name}")
```

Тут уже добавляется переменная, длину которой мы ещё не знаем, но когда будет инициализирована переменная, то узнаем. Собственно, строка должна быть длины 35, слово "Товар:" 6 символов, тогда 35 - 6 = 29, а также не забываем про неинициализированную переменную, тогда 29 - len(name) - столько нам необходимо пробелов до заполнения строки до 35 символов.

Дальше аналогично.

Если смотреть на Ваш пример, то

```
print(f"Товар: {product_name: >28}"[:35])
```

Здесь, например, будет обрезаться строка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
product = input()
price = int(input())
weight = int(input())
money = int(input())
cost = str(weight) + "кг * " + str(price) + "руб/кг"
print("================Чек================")
print(f"Товар:{product:>29}")
print(f"Цена:{cost:>30}")
print(f"Итого:{price * weight:>26}руб")
print(f"Внесено:{money:>24}руб")
print(f"Сдача:{money - (price * weight):>26}руб")
print("=" * 35)
```

Зачем здесь создавать отдельную переменную, почему нельзя решить в самой f-строке(я про то, где цена)

Answer (score -1):

Откуда берутся значения очевидно. 35 минус длина уже известного текста, это уменьшаемое. Длина переменных - это вычитаемое. Разница заполняется пробелами.

Ваше решение не принимается, потому что строка с ценой иногда короче остальных.

Comment: Друг, если бы это было очевидно, то, очевидно, я бы здесь об этом не спрашивал. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

С этой задачей в курсе есть учебные материалы, там нет оператора "len()", т.е. пользователь не может его использовать (подразумевается, что еще не изучено). Система может и примет решение выше. Но все таки, основываясь на изученном курсе, считаю правильным такой вариант:

```
product = input()
price = int(input())
weight = int(input())
money = int(input())
cost = str(weight) + "кг * " + str(price) + "руб/кг"
print("================Чек================")
print(f"Товар:{product:>29}")
print(f"Цена:{cost:>30}")
print(f"Итого:{price * weight:>26}руб")
print(f"Внесено:{money:>24}руб")
print(f"Сдача:{money - (price * weight):>26}руб")
print("=" * 35)
```